# is it possible to accesss communities information via the soap api from the perspective of a communities user?

Tags: api, community, soap

I would like to be able to retrieve Communities groups/posts/likes information available to a community user via the SOAP API (using an api user credentials), I understand that there are already lots of options in implementing communities but I need to access Communities information from an existing php application.

The setup I'm working on at the moment is a PHP web site that already consumes SOAP web services defined in the enterprise WSDL, but I would like to expose very limited communities information (i.e. a list of groups). The PHP website knows the communities userid etc. so I was hoping to just make some calls to the SOAP API to get "all groups for communities user x" or "all posts visible to user x in group y"

I've spent quite some time googling, but I'm beginning to think that this either isn't possible, or is a bad idea!